# iPhone Facebook Graph API library

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there an library for the iPhone using the new Facebook Graph API yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library is great: http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2

I am using it with great success in a current iPad project.

Update: Author just posted code to github: http://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API

Update: Please check https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/issues/4 if you find post to FB crashing while using code

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have seen and trying to write something myself has been without success.  I am VERY disappointed with Facebook and there lack of support in this area especially since they want developers to move over to the API, however iPhone developers are SOL at the moment which is a shame since using their current SDK is a pain in the ass with all of their callbacks and delegates.  It is not very clean at all.

Comment: Here is my blog about a solution: http://blog.corywiles.com/facebook-graph-api-with-a-native-iphone-appli

Comment: Cory, how is the user logging in? Or is that provided with your "quick web app"?

Comment: That is provided by the quick webapp.  The first request is made to: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://yoursite.com/callback

Once that request has been made then the user will login to fb @ fb and then will be redirect to your callback url with an access_token provided by fb which your app will use to make requests on the user's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

FB Graph API SDK for iPhone is rumored to be released during WWDC. Android SDK is already officially announced (but not released, yet).

Comment: Didn't Android come out yesterday? Or was that the announcement only?