# Open Graph API facebook IOS SDK sample

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to create a application iOS with a function Add to Watchlist. 
When user see a Film or smt, he can press Add to Watchlist. App with post to facebook and his friend can see it via facebook or this app. 
Like app: Flixster on Appstore. But i don't know and don't have any ideal for this function. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this links.You will get some good ideas to implement it.

1.[iPhone Facebook Graph API library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692553/iphone-facebook-graph-api-library)

2.http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2

3.https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk